# What are the advantages and disadvantages of 3d array in Mathematica

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, 3d, wolfram-mathematica

Edited...

Thanks for every one to try to help me!!!

i am trying to make a Finite Element Analysis in Mathemetica.... We can obtain all the local stiffness matrices that has 8x8 dimensions. I mean there are 2000 matrices they are similar but not same. every local stiffness matrix shown like a function that name is KK. For example KK[1] is first element local stiffness matrix

i am trying to assemble all the local matrices to make global stiffness matrix. To make it easy:

```
Do[K[e][i][j]=KK[[e]][[i]][[j]],{e,2000},{i,8},{j,8}]....edited
```

Here is my question....  this equality can affect the analysis time...If yes what can i do to improve this...

in matlab this is named as 3d array but i don't know what is called in Mathematica

what are the advantages and  disadvantages of this explanation type in Mathematica...is t faster or is it easy way

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to understand what your question is, so you might want to reformulate it.

As others have mentioned, there is no advantage to be expected from a switch from a 3D array to `DownValues` or `SubValues`. In fact you will then move from accessing data-structures to pattern matching, which is powerful and the real strength of Mathematica but not very efficient for what you plan to do, so I would strongly suggest to stay in the realm of ordinary arrays.

There is another thing that might not be clear for someone more familiar with matlab than with Mathematica: In Mathematica the "default" for arrays behave a lot like cell arrays in matlab: each entry can contain arbitrary content and they don't need to be rectangular (as High Performance Mark has mentioned they are just expressions with a head `List` and can roughly be compared to matlab cell arrays). But if such a nested list is a rectangular array and every element of it is of the same type such arrays can be converted to so called `PackedArrays`. `PackedArrays` are much more memory efficient and will also speed up many calculations, they behave in many respect like regular ("not-cell") arrays in matlab. This conversion is often done implicitly from functions like `Table`, which will oten return a packed array automatically. But if you are interested in efficiency it is a good idea to check with `` Developer`PackedArrayQ `` and convert explicitly with `` Developer`ToPackedArray `` if necessary. If you are working with `PackedArrays` speed and memory efficiency of many operations are much better and usually comparable to verctorized operations on normal matlab arrays. Unfortunately it can happen that packed arrays get "unpacked" by some operations, so if calculations become slow it is usually a good idea to check if that has happend.

Neither "normal" arrays nor `PackedArrays` are restricted in the rank (called `Depth` in Mathematica) they can have, so you can of course create and use "3D arrays" just as you can in matlab. I have never experienced or would know of any efficiency penalties when doing so.

It probably is of interest that newer versions of Mathematica (>= 10) bring the finite element method as one of the solver methods for `NDSolve`, so if you are not doing this as an exercise you might want to have a look what is available already, there is quite excessive documentation about it.

A final remark is that you can instead of `kk[[e]][[i]][[j]]` use the much more readable form `kk[[e,i,j]]` which is also easier and less error prone to type...

Answer (score 0):

extended comment i guess, but

```
 KK[e][[i]][[j]]
```

is not the `(e,i,j)` element of a "3d array". Note the single
brackets on the `e`.  When you use the single brackets you are not denoting an array or list element but a `DownValue`, which is quite different from a list element.

If you do for example,

```
 f[1]=0
 f[2]=2
```

...

the resulting `f` appears similar to an array, but is actually more akin to an overloaded function in some other language.  It is convenient because the indices need not be contiguous or even integers, but there is a significant performance drawback if you ever want to operate on the structure as a list.

Your 'do' loop example would almost certainly be better written as:

```
 kk = Table[ k[e][i][j] ,{e,2000},{i,8},{j,8} ]
```

( Your loop wont even work as-is unless you previously "initialized" each of the `kk[e]` as an 8x8 array. )

Note now the list elements are all double bracketed, ie `kk[[e]][[i]][[j]]` or `kk[[e,i,j]]`

Comment: Sorry for wrong writing i change it Do[K[e][i][j]=KK[[e]][[i]][[j]],{e,2000},{i,8},{j,8}]....edited

Comment: what i wrote still applies.  Defining `K[e][i][j]` , that is a symbol with 128 thousand `DownValues` that cannot be addressed by array operators, is almost certainly a *horrible* thing to do.